# Open link when doubleclicking on table row with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, double-click

I have a `table` that looks like this:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
      <tr class='tablehead'>
        <th>Test</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class='tablecell'>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

1. I want to be able to double click on a row and then trigger a link.
2. An ID has to be transmitted somehow. Where should I define this? This allows me to edit the selected row afterwards.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: All of the answers below are ok. Just remember that, for working with jQuery, you must declare the library in your head tag html code. As any other javascript file. Of course, you must download it before.

Comment: Yes you are right, but unfortunatlly I can only accept one. It worked as expected :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do you have *any* jQuery you've written yet? Here's a headstart...

Define your ID in the row:

```
<tr id="something">...</tr>
```

Then use something like this:

```
$('tr').dblclick(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  //do something with id
})
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tablecell').click(function() {
        return false;
    }).dblclick(function() {
        window.open("your_url");
        return false;
    });
});
```

and you could create a hidden field and populate that field with the id when double clicked.

Answer (score 5):

This may help you:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#table tr').click(function() {
        return false;
    }).dblclick(function() {
        window.location = url;
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

**Working demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Xr7LC/ (created from the sample code you provided)

1. Use `dblclick` api http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/
2. You can use `$(this).attr('id')` to get the id, and obviously you will define the id in a tag.

**jQuery code for dblclick:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table >thead > tr').dblclick(function() {
    alert('Row dblclicked');
        alert($(this).attr('class'));
    });
});​
```

Comment: I think this is a good method, but perhaps some complicated for dooonot, at this stage.